# How can I be notified of calls and SMS messages from my iphone?

Tags: 18.04, iphone

I would like to be notified if my iphone is ringing or if I receive an SMS on Ubuntu.

I don't mind if I can't answer the call from ubuntu.

Using Iphone 6S and Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: [KDE Connect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) But I have no idea if IOS supports it at all.  https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/8swa2l/kde_connect_ios_support/

Comment: Alternatively, look into Pushbullet (https://www.pushbullet.com/) in combination with IFTTT (https://ifttt.com/). You run the IFTTT app on your iPhone and configure it to send a Pushbullet message to your Ubuntu system. Pushbullet works as a browser extension.